# questions about try_files to replace rewrite in nginx conf

Tags: wordpress, file, nginx, url-rewriting, reduce

I have a nginx conf for my wordpress site. it's too much rewrite.
I want to replace the rewrite to try_file and reduce the conf file.

This is my nginx conf:

```
server
{
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    index index.php;
    root  /home/domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ^~ /topics/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        rewrite ^/topics/(.*).html$ $scheme://$host/topics/$1/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/topics/(.*).html/(.*)$ $scheme://$host/topics/$1/$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^/topics/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ $scheme://$host/topics/$4/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/topics/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ $scheme://$host/topics/$4/$5 permanent;
        rewrite ^/topics/tag/(.*)$ $scheme://$host/tag/$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/topics/category/(.*)$ $scheme://$host/category/$1 permanent;
    }
    location ~ ^/topics/.+\.php$ {
            set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
            real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fcgi.conf;
    }
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ $scheme://$host/topics/$4/ permanent;

    location ~ .*\.php(\/.*)*$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fcgi.conf;
    }

    access_log off;
}
```

How can I reduce and replace it? Thank you.